# TYPO3 Extbase: How to store NULL in DB for empty numeric fields?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

In a form Viewhelper I have lots of numeric fields, which should be empty by default, not filled with '0' or '0.00'.

I need this, because there should be a different handling of the data in the saveAction, depending on left empty fields or filled in values (including 0).

For this reason I set the field properties in the database table to NULL by default, like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tx_myext_domain_model_result` (
    mw double (10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    mw2 double (10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    ....
);
```

TCA looks like this:

```
  'mw' => array(
    ...
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'double2,null'
        )
    ),
```

Also, in the Result model class, the corresponding properties are initialized with NULL;

```
/**
 * mw
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $mw = null;
```

I did this check to assure that NULL is handled over to the getter for empty form fields:

```
public function setMw($mw) {
        if ($mw == NULL)
            $this->mw = 999;
        else
            $this->mw = $mw;
}
```

This did what I excepted: The mw field DB was set to '999' for a empty form field.

But now, switched back to normal setter,

```
public function setMw($mw) {
       $this->mw = $mw;
}
```

fields in the DB table are only left NULL when all other form fields are left empty, too. I.e. as soon as I enter a value in one of the form fields, all other empty form fields are set to '0' on save.

Adding `null` to the TCA eval field didn't do the trick, neither.

How can I change this behaviour? I'm using TYPO3 6.2.x

Comment: Whats your TCA configuration? Maybe you can use `type converter` in your controller (`initializeAction`).

Comment: Added TCA. How to use type converter? I don't wont to change the type; I it's just NULL that should stay NULL. The action shouldn't be the problem, as NULL arrives in the getter.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: in initializeAction set null for the property
step 2: the idea with checking $mw is null is preaty good idea. TYPO3 not always do what you can assume using logical thinking :) So check `if(is_null($mw)) $this->mw = null`

this two things should do the trick

you can also set a default value in setter param

`setMw($mw = null)`

Comment: I don't understand why there is a difference between `$this->mw = $mw` and  `$this->mw = NULL` when $mw  _is_ NULL ? What do you mean with set null in initializeAction? The property shouldn't be always null, only when the form field is left empty... `is_null()` does not work because 0 should be stored in the DB.

Comment: 1. TYPO3 may not set null when you think it will set
2. initializeAction is an action that is in every model but you don't need to use it. It initialize diffrent things. For example if you have collection than i this action you will have initialization of it. It is kind of constructor
3. If null should be only when it is empty then when you will set default value of property to null it should do the trick. I wrote that: `setMw($mw = null)` this will set null as default

Comment: 1. This has nothing to do with TYPO3, it's just PHP - or logical: It's the same thing like saying `$mw = 1; $this->mw = $mw` and `$this->mw = 1;` will have a different effect . 2. I know what intitializeAction is, but how will this solve my problem? Why should I set $mw=NULL in there when it's NULL anyway? NULL arrives  in he setter, so the action wouldn't change anything 3. I just want to store NULL in the DB when I set $mw=NULL (equal to a empty form field). But for some reason, Extbase will not allow this. `setMw($mw = null)` and calling `setMw(null)`should lead to the same result.

Comment: About `it's just PHP` you can be suprised how many times i've bashed my head into the wall cause i thought like you ;) back to the problem. empty form field will not always set null in setter method in extbase. I think you should just try to set default null as param of setter.
about the initializeAction you`re correct. if we're talking about existing object then it will have no efekt, it will have efect only while creating new object. still I think that null as default in setter can help. Did you tried it ?

Comment: :) You got me - I didn't try it yesterday. But now I checked it, and it doesn't work, neither. BTW I got a hint that `if ($mw == NULL)` doesn't do what I expect it to do, because `0 == NULL` is true... So it's still all logical. I have to check with triple `===`

Comment: then I think you can write an `if` in your setter method to be sure that null is set. this is a bit stupid but maybe it will work